# Project Tango: Augmented Reality navigation with ADF not working

Tags: shortest-path, google-project-tango, quadtree, android-augmented-reality

Working on an indoor navigation app using project tango by referring [this repository](https://github.com/inovex/tango-ar-navigation-example). It updates all the valid poses and finds path when the starting and ending points are set to the adapter. It uses A* algorithm to find out the shortest path between two points, as it has already constructed a Quadtree for the given coordinates which are extracted from valid poses. It works well with respect to *Start Of Service*

It does not giving me path or gives zero-sized path, when I load an ADF and update the poses with respect to ADF. Even I had tried collecting all the coordinates from valid poses, constructed Quadtree and tried to find out the path. It returns 0 sized path, where the path is a collection of Vector2 objects

Activity class

```
    public class SoSPathActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener {

    // frame pairs for adf based ar pose tracking
    public static final TangoCoordinateFramePair SOS_T_DEVICE_FRAME_PAIR =
            new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
                    TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
                    TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE);
    public static final TangoCoordinateFramePair DEVICE_T_PREVIOUS_FRAME_PAIR =
            new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
                    TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_PREVIOUS_DEVICE_POSE,
                    TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE);

    // This changes the Camera Texture and Intrinsics
    protected static final int ACTIVE_CAMERA_INTRINSICS = TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR;
    protected static final int INVALID_TEXTURE_ID = -1;
    private static final String TAG = SoSPathActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected AtomicBoolean tangoIsConnected = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    protected AtomicBoolean tangoFrameIsAvailable = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    protected Tango tango;
    protected TangoUx tangoUx;
    protected TangoCameraIntrinsics intrinsics;
    protected DeviceExtrinsics extrinsics;

    protected int connectedTextureId;
    protected double rgbFrameTimestamp;
    protected double cameraPoseTimestamp;

    protected SoSPathRenderer renderer;


    RajawaliSurfaceView mainSurfaceView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TangoUxLayout uxLayout;
    MapView mapView;
    private TangoPointCloudManager mPointCloudManager;

    private static DeviceExtrinsics setupExtrinsics(Tango tango) {
        // Create camera to IMU transform.
        TangoCoordinateFramePair framePair = new TangoCoordinateFramePair();
        framePair.baseFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
        framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
        TangoPoseData imuToRgbPose = tango.getPoseAtTime(0.0, framePair);

        // Create device to IMU transform.
        framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
        TangoPoseData imuToDevicePose = tango.getPoseAtTime(0.0, framePair);

        // Create depth camera to IMU transform.
        framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH;
        TangoPoseData imuToDepthPose = tango.getPoseAtTime(0.0, framePair);

        return new DeviceExtrinsics(imuToDevicePose, imuToRgbPose, imuToDepthPose);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tango = new Tango(this);
        tangoUx = new TangoUx(this);
        renderer = new SoSPathRenderer(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        mainSurfaceView = (RajawaliSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.gl_main_surface_view);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        uxLayout = (TangoUxLayout)findViewById(R.id.tango_ux_layout);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tangoUx.setLayout(uxLayout);
        renderer.renderVirtualObjects(true);
        mainSurfaceView.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
        mainSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
        mapView.setFloorPlanData(renderer.getFloorPlanData());

        mPointCloudManager = new TangoPointCloudManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        synchronized (this) {
            if (tangoIsConnected.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                try {
                    connectTango();
                    connectRenderer();
                } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                    message(R.string.exception_out_of_date);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        synchronized (this) {
            if (tangoIsConnected.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                renderer.getCurrentScene().clearFrameCallbacks();
                tango.disconnectCamera(ACTIVE_CAMERA_INTRINSICS);
                connectedTextureId = INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;
                tango.disconnect();
                tangoUx.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.set_start_point:
                renderer.setStartPoint(getCurrentPose(), extrinsics);
                break;
            case R.id.set_end_point:
                renderer.setEndPoint(getCurrentPose(), extrinsics
                );
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
        if (cameraId == ACTIVE_CAMERA_INTRINSICS) {
            tangoFrameIsAvailable.set(true);
            mainSurfaceView.requestRender();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTangoEvent(TangoEvent event) {
        if (tangoUx != null) {
            tangoUx.updateTangoEvent(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
        if (tangoUx != null) {
            tangoUx.updatePoseStatus(pose.statusCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
        if (tangoUx != null) {
            tangoUx.updateXyzCount(xyzIj.xyzCount);
        }
    }

    private void message(final int message_resource) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message_resource, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void setupCameraProperties(Tango tango) {
        extrinsics = setupExtrinsics(tango);
        intrinsics = tango.getCameraIntrinsics(ACTIVE_CAMERA_INTRINSICS);
    }


    protected void connectTango() {
        TangoUx.StartParams params = new TangoUx.StartParams();
        tangoUx.start(params);
        TangoConfig config = tango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LOWLATENCYIMUINTEGRATION, true);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
        tango.connect(config);
        ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        framePairs.add(SOS_T_DEVICE_FRAME_PAIR);
        framePairs.add(DEVICE_T_PREVIOUS_FRAME_PAIR);
        tango.connectListener(framePairs, this);
        setupCameraProperties(tango);
    }


    public TangoPoseData getCurrentPose() {
        return tango.getPoseAtTime(rgbFrameTimestamp, SOS_T_DEVICE_FRAME_PAIR);
    }

    int position = 0;
    protected void connectRenderer() {
        renderer.getCurrentScene().registerFrameCallback(new ScenePreFrameCallbackAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onPreFrame(long sceneTime, double deltaTime) {
                synchronized (SoSPathActivity.this) {
                    if (!tangoIsConnected.get()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!renderer.isSceneCameraConfigured()) {
                        renderer.setProjectionMatrix(intrinsics);
                    }
                    if (connectedTextureId != renderer.getTextureId()) {
                        tango.connectTextureId(ACTIVE_CAMERA_INTRINSICS, renderer.getTextureId());
                        connectedTextureId = renderer.getTextureId();
                    }
                    if (tangoFrameIsAvailable.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                        rgbFrameTimestamp = tango.updateTexture(ACTIVE_CAMERA_INTRINSICS);
                    }
                    if (rgbFrameTimestamp > cameraPoseTimestamp) {
                        TangoPoseData currentPose = getCurrentPose();
                        if (currentPose != null && currentPose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {
                            renderer.updateRenderCameraPose(currentPose, extrinsics, position);
                            cameraPoseTimestamp = currentPose.timestamp;
                            position++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is Renderer class

```
    public class SoSPathRenderer extends TangoRajawaliRenderer {

    public static final int QUAD_TREE_START = -60;
    public static final int QUAD_TREE_RANGE = 120;
    private static final String TAG = SoSPathRenderer.class.getSimpleName();
    private final QuadTree data;
    // Rajawali texture used to render the Tango color camera
    private ATexture mTangoCameraTexture;
    // Keeps track of whether the scene camera has been configured
    private boolean mSceneCameraConfigured;

    private FloorPlan floorPlan;
    private Pose startPoint;
    private Pose endPoint;
    private List<Cube> pathCubes = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean fillPath = false;
    private Material blue;
    private boolean renderVirtualObjects;

    private Vector3 startingPoint;
    private Vector3 endingPoint;

    public SoSPathRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        data = new QuadTree(new Vector2(QUAD_TREE_START, QUAD_TREE_START), QUAD_TREE_RANGE, 8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initScene() {
        // Create a quad covering the whole background and assign a texture to it where the
        // Tango color camera contents will be rendered.
        ScreenQuad backgroundQuad = new ScreenQuad();
        Material tangoCameraMaterial = new Material();
        tangoCameraMaterial.setColorInfluence(0);
        // We need to use Rajawali's {@code StreamingTexture} since it sets up the texture
        // for GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES rendering
        mTangoCameraTexture =
                new StreamingTexture("camera", (StreamingTexture.ISurfaceListener) null);
        try {
            tangoCameraMaterial.addTexture(mTangoCameraTexture);
            backgroundQuad.setMaterial(tangoCameraMaterial);
        } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception creating texture for RGB camera contents", e);
        }
        getCurrentScene().addChildAt(backgroundQuad, 0);

        // Add a directional light in an arbitrary direction.
        DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(1, 0.2, -1);
        light.setColor(1, 1, 1);
        light.setPower(0.8f);
        light.setPosition(3, 2, 4);
        getCurrentScene().addLight(light);

        blue = new Material();
        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        floorPlan = new FloorPlan(data);
        getCurrentScene().addChild(floorPlan);
        floorPlan.setVisible(renderVirtualObjects);

    }

    /**
     * Update the scene camera based on the provided pose in Tango start of service frame.
     * The device pose should match the pose of the device at the time the last rendered RGB
     * frame, which can be retrieved with this.getTimestamp();
     * NOTE: This must be called from the OpenGL render thread - it is not thread safe.
     */
    public void updateRenderCameraPose(TangoPoseData devicePose, DeviceExtrinsics extrinsics, int position) {
        Pose cameraPose = ScenePoseCalculator.toOpenGlCameraPose(devicePose, extrinsics);
        getCurrentCamera().setRotation(cameraPose.getOrientation());
        getCurrentCamera().setPosition(cameraPose.getPosition());

        Vector3 vector3 = cameraPose.getPosition();
        floorPlan.setTrajectoryPosition(cameraPose.getPosition());
        Log.d(TAG, "P: " + cameraPose.toString());

        /*if(position<getLatestPathPoints().size()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "XXX Adding ADF Pose position into FloorPlan (x,y,z): " + getLatestPathPoints().get(position).x + ", "
                    + getLatestPathPoints().get(position).y + ", " + getLatestPathPoints().get(position).z);
            floorPlan.setTrajectoryPosition(getLatestPathPoints().get(position));
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * It returns the ID currently assigned to the texture where the Tango color camera contents
     * should be rendered.
     * NOTE: This must be called from the OpenGL render thread - it is not thread safe.
     */
    public int getTextureId() {
        return mTangoCameraTexture == null ? -1 : mTangoCameraTexture.getTextureId();
    }

    /**
     * We need to override this method to mark the camera for re-configuration (set proper
     * projection matrix) since it will be reset by Rajawali on surface changes.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        super.onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(gl, width, height);
        mSceneCameraConfigured = false;
    }

    public boolean isSceneCameraConfigured() {
        return mSceneCameraConfigured;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the projection matrix for the scene camera to match the parameters of the color camera,
     * provided by the {@code TangoCameraIntrinsics}.
     */
    public void setProjectionMatrix(TangoCameraIntrinsics intrinsics) {
        Matrix4 projectionMatrix = ScenePoseCalculator.calculateProjectionMatrix(
                intrinsics.width, intrinsics.height,
                intrinsics.fx, intrinsics.fy, intrinsics.cx, intrinsics.cy);
        getCurrentCamera().setProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                                 float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep,
                                 int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRender(long ellapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
        super.onRender(ellapsedRealtime, deltaTime);

        // add routing cubes to scene graph if available
        if (fillPath) {
            for (Cube pathCube : pathCubes) {
                getCurrentScene().removeChild(pathCube);
            }
            pathCubes.clear();
            PathFinder finder = new PathFinder(floorPlan.getData());
            try {
                List<Vector2> path = finder.findPathBetween(startPoint.getPosition(), endPoint.getPosition());
                //List<Vector2> path = finder.findPathBetween(startingPoint, endingPoint);
                Log.d(TAG, "XXX Pathpoints: " + path.size());
                for (Vector2 vector2 : path) {
                    Cube cube = new Cube(0.2f);
                    cube.setMaterial(blue);
                    cube.setPosition(new Vector3(vector2.getX(), -1.2, vector2.getY()));
                    getCurrentScene().addChild(cube);
                    pathCubes.add(cube);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onRender: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                fillPath = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setStartPoint(TangoPoseData currentPose, DeviceExtrinsics extrinsics) {
        startPoint = ScenePoseCalculator.toOpenGlCameraPose(currentPose, extrinsics);
        floorPlan.addPoint(startPoint.getPosition());
        if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null) {
            fillPath = true;
        }
        /*startingPoint = getLatestPathPoints().get(0);
        floorPlan.addPoint(startingPoint);
        if (startingPoint != null && endingPoint != null) {
            fillPath = true;
        }*/
    }

    public void setEndPoint(TangoPoseData currentPose, DeviceExtrinsics extrinsics) {
        endPoint = ScenePoseCalculator.toOpenGlCameraPose(currentPose, extrinsics);
        floorPlan.addPoint(endPoint.getPosition());
        if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null) {
            fillPath = true;
        }
        /*endingPoint = getLatestPathPoints().get(getLatestPathPoints().size()-10);
        floorPlan.addPoint(endingPoint);
        if (startingPoint != null && endingPoint != null) {
            fillPath = true;
        }*/
    }

    public QuadTree getFloorPlanData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void renderVirtualObjects(boolean renderObjects) {
        renderVirtualObjects = renderObjects;
        if (this.floorPlan != null)
            this.floorPlan.setVisible(renderObjects);
    }

}
```

I am not sure, what I am missing here to get the path after loading an ADF. Please update me if anyone has experience on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering, but I haven't enough reputation to write a comment. Can you please show me your code / project on github or something else? It have to work also with learning mode. I can imagine that the tablet isn't relocalized after loading an adf an so the pose data isn't valid.

**EDIT:**
Check if your frame pair is like the following:

```
 /** Record Device to Area Description as the main frame pair to be used for device pose queries. */
private static final TangoCoordinateFramePair FRAME_PAIR = new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
        TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
        TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE);
```

And check if you have area learning mode on and loaded the adf correctly:

```
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LEARNINGMODE, true); //learning mode on
config.putString(TangoConfig.KEY_STRING_AREADESCRIPTION, mLoadedADFPair.getUuid()); //load adf
```

Then check if you ask for your pose data in a way similiar to that:

```
TangoPoseData lastFramePose = mTango.getPoseAtTime(mRgbTimestampGlThread,
                        FRAME_PAIR);
if (lastFramePose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {

       // Device is re-located!               

       // Update the camera pose from the renderer
       mRenderer.updateRenderCameraPose(lastFramePose);
       mCameraPoseTimestamp = lastFramePose.timestamp;
} else {
       Log.w(TAG, "Can't get device pose at time: " + mRgbTimestampGlThread);
}
```

Before there is a valid pose data available it may take up to 3-5 minutes. Walk around and don't give up.

Comment: After loading ADF, it is recognised...and I'm updating the pose (Device wrt ADF),.  added code with question..

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363225/check-if-area-is-localized-in-loaded-adf/37374225#37374225