# Area Description: Wrong pose happens after the state turns "localized"

Tags: google-project-tango

This problem happens recently to me and I have done several tests but nothing seems helpful. So I wonder if anyone has met this problem.

[The code that I use and I also put detail description in the document folder](https://github.com/ZoutaoWen/area_description.git)

The problem is that after my device have localized in the area (Load ADF on and Learning mode on), the coordinate between the current position and the origin in the ADF is wrong so is the coordinate between the two origins (the origin I start the localization and the one in ADF).

[The result shows the wrong coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4tWe.png)

I've noticed that localization can be done in two different pipeline[(usefule note)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363225/check-if-area-is-localized-in-loaded-adf) and I tried another pipeline (Load ADF on and Learning mode off). Yes, it works but I am still wondering why the first one is not working and the differences between the two pipeline (the official website gives just the phenomenon of the two situation but haven't explained why).

I'll be very pleased if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Java Tango development, but under Unity, when you load an ADF in learning mode (to expand it), the pipeline is different than just loading the ADF with learning mode OFF.

A problem that had already been noticed is that when the learning mode is ON, relocalizing in the ADF is way longer than when learning mode is OFF.

Actually I am not sure about it but what may be the problem, is that when learning mode is ON, TANGO might as well update the base frame of the ADF as new features are learnt. So I would check that out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and what you think is as same as I think. It is strange that Google hasn't given the details related to the two pipeline and the reason. 
I even tested the precision of the two pipeline. The one with learning mode ON even has a lower precision than the one with learning mode OFF. However, the one with learning mode ON can update the base frame which means that it can modify the drift in ADF. Meanwhile, the one with learning mode OFF can't do this because it can't save ADF.